# Is there a simpler way to change color instead of using lambda?

Tags: pandas

Here are scores for some students

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[71,62,13], [75,76,77]], columns=list("ABC"))
df
```

[image]

The scores that are lower than 60 need to be marked red

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ["color: #ff33aa" if c < 60 else ''
                          for c in x])
```

[image]

All the jobs are done.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: It's hard to define "simpler" you could use `applymap` -> `df.style.applymap(lambda x: "color: #ff33aa" if x < 60 else '')` which would remove the need for the list comprehension.

Comment: You could also build the styling rules with `np.where` -> `df.style.apply(lambda _: np.where(df < 60, "color: #ff33aa", ''), axis=None)`